# UDP Client Not Sending

Tags: c#, .net, windows, udp, firewall

I am working on a autodiscovery client for some equipment that I work with frequently and I'm having an issue where for some users the **UDP packet is not being sent out** (It doesn't appear in Wireshark).

The code behind it is fairly simple and I think it's related to the Windows firewall somehow, but I cant find a solution so far.

Can anybody offer any suggestions on next steps to take?

The relevant code:

```
class AutoDiscovery : IDisposable
{
    private UdpClient Udp;
    private static IPEndPoint BroadcastEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 12345);
    private List<byte> AutoDiscoverPacket = new List<byte>();

    private bool _IsDisposed = false;
    public bool IsDisposed
    {
        get { return _IsDisposed; }
        private set { _IsDisposed = value; }
    }

    public AutoDiscovery()
    {
        Udp = new UdpClient();
        Udp.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        Udp.EnableBroadcast = true;
        Udp.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        Udp.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345));
        ReceiveDataAsync(ReceiveDataCallback);

        AutoDiscoverPacket.AddRange(new byte[] { 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x04, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00 });
        AutoDiscoverPacket.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SomeStaticString"));
        while (AutoDiscoverPacket.Count < 123)
        {
            AutoDiscoverPacket.Add(0x00);
        }
    }


    public void Discover()
    {
        if (IsDisposed) { throw new ObjectDisposedException("AutoDiscovery"); }
        Udp.Send(AutoDiscoverPacket.ToArray(), AutoDiscoverPacket.Count, BroadcastEP);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the rogue machines have more than one network? have you confirmed its trying to send?

Comment: They may have more than one network.  I'll investigate that.  I don't see the packets in wireshark to they're not being transmitted but there shouldn't be anything in the code preventing them from sending.

Comment: no but if your code picks the wrong network...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did appear that using

```
Udp.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345));
```

Allowed Windows to decide which adapter to bind to on it's own.  I was able to get a list of adapter IP addresses using the following code and create a UdpClient bound to each one.

```
private List<IPAddress> GetEndpoints()
    {
        List<IPAddress> AddressList = new List<IPAddress>();
        NetworkInterface[] Interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach(NetworkInterface I in Interfaces)
        {
            if ((I.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet || I.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211) && I.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                foreach (var Unicast in I.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (Unicast.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        AddressList.Add(Unicast.Address);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return AddressList;
    }
```